# dynamic File inside folders not reading with React and preval.macro

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to build an app which will show list of items read from a folder inside my create-react-app and it will read and show the file inside the folder.

```
import preval from 'preval.macro';
import '../index.css'

const components = preval
    ` const fs = require('fs');
  const files = fs.readdirSync('src/atoms');
  module.exports = files;
`

const AtomList = () => {

    const [newFileName, setNewFileName] = useState('avatar');


    const fileUnderComponent = preval
        `   const fs = require('fs')
            const path = require('path');
            const file = fs.readFileSync('src/atoms/${newFileName}/${newFileName}.js');
            module.exports = file.toString();
        `;

    const setNewComponent = (componentName) => {
        setNewFileName(componentName)
    }

    const eachAtom = (component) => {
        return (
            <ul><li className="list-item-group" onClick={() => setNewComponent(component)}>{component}</li></ul>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="list-group inlineBlock atomList width20">
                <div>List of Reusable Components</div>
                {components.map((component, i) => {
                    return eachAtom(component)
                })}
            </div>
            <div className="list-group inlineBlock atomDescription width80">
                {typeof fileUnderComponent === 'string' ? fileUnderComponent : null}
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default AtomList
```

In the above component, if i hardcode newFileName as 'avatar' the contents of the file renders but when i switch the components on clicking them the newFileName changes but fileUnderComponent doesn't render anything.

I think probably due to readFileSync operation which takes some time. I have tried putting it in setTimeout but no luck.

Where could i go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preval evaluates the code at build time therefore it won't be possible to run it on updating your state. The following code to *extract content of files* for preval works fine.

```
const contentOfComponents = preval`
const fs = require("fs");
const files = fs.readdirSync("src/atoms");
const content = files.map(filename => {
  const fs = require("fs");
  const url = 'src/atoms/'+filename+'/'+filename+'.js';
  return fs.readFileSync(url).toString();
})
module.exports = content`;
```

You can use this `contentOfComponents` which is an array of the contents of the files by mapping them against your `components` array and then displaying the appropriate content when the filename is clicked.

**Code From the Question after incorporating the changes as mentioned above**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import preval from "preval.macro";
import shortid from "shortid";

const components = preval`
const fs = require("fs");
const files = fs.readdirSync("src/atoms");
module.exports = files`;

const contentOfComponents = preval`
const fs = require("fs");
const files = fs.readdirSync("src/atoms");
const content = files.map(filename => {
  const fs = require("fs");
  const url = 'src/atoms/'+filename+'/'+filename+'.js';
  return fs.readFileSync(url).toString();
})
module.exports = content`;

const AtomList = () => {
  const [fileUnderComponent, setFileUnderComponent] = useState(null);

  const setNewComponent = componentName => {
    const _index = components.indexOf(componentName);
    setFileUnderComponent(contentOfComponents[_index]);
  };

  const eachAtom = component => {
    return (
      <li
        key={shortid.generate()}
        className="list-item-group"
        onClick={() => setNewComponent(component)}
      >
        {component}
      </li>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="list-group inlineBlock atomList width20">
        <div>List of Reusable Components</div>
        <ul>
          {components.map(component => {
            return eachAtom(component);
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="list-group inlineBlock atomDescription width80">
        {typeof fileUnderComponent === "string" ? fileUnderComponent : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AtomList;
```

Also your `eachAtom` *function* doesn't need to return a `<ul>`.

**Discarded! This was the first impression**

This could be a syntactical error. In your line `const file = fs.readFileSync('src/atoms/${newFileName}/${newFileName}.js');` are you sure you are using *back-ticks* and not single quotes?

This might solve it:

`` const file = fs.readFileSync(`src/atoms/${newFileName}/${newFileName}.js`); ``

back-tick key is usually on the top left corner just below the Esc key and to the left of number 1 key.

Comment: @rajdeepchandra If this doesn't help you can comment here and I will try to look into the problem further. Thanks.

Comment: Yup i missed the backticks. still no luck though.

Comment: @rajdeepchandra I hope this helps. Do leave your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that even of you preval your filenames separately into an array and try to get contents of those files you are not able to do that. Which I believe would need more understanding on the order of execution of preval(s) in the code.

Comment: Thanks mate. i see what you have done here.This works